# How to accomplish Character factor conversion of data frame to numeric type?

Tags: r

```
str(my$a) 
chr [1:7043] "No" "No" "Yes" "Yes" "Yes" "No" "No" "No" "No" "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
```

I want to convert in to 0and1's i tried using as.numeric with other combinations.None materialized.Can any tell me the way.

Comment: Downvote for lack of effort at searching.

Comment: I tried to search.None of the solution suited my problem. Whatever posted as comment worked.But now i am not able to see. Can you please help

Comment: The comment was the same as one of the answers in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `Vec_of_1s_and_0s <- ifelse(my$a == "No", 0, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

We can just do

```
as.integer(my$a=="Yes")
```